# Adding image array to Realm database

Tags: ios, swift, database, image, realm

How can I save a UIImage array at the Realm DB?

My object class:

```
class DataBase: Object{    
    dynamic var code: String = ""
    dynamic var capture: [UIImage] = [] // it doesn't work 
}
```

My "add to DataBase" function:

```
func addToDB() {
    let realm = try! Realm()        
    let myObject = DataBase()
    myObject.code = self.code
    myObject.capture = self.capture // here should something better            

    try! realm.write {
        realm.add(myObject)
    }
}
```

As I understand it is possible to save path's of images at the DB. But how can I do it for array?

Comment: Use Realm's List instead of Swift Array.

Comment: Convert the array into base64 encoded string. http://iosdevelopertips.com/core-services/encode-decode-using-base64.html and send that value.

Comment: If you want to save image into realm, you need to encode them and save as NSData, thats just never advised, just save the image into the app's documents folder, and save its path/name into Realm, also, read the docs

Answer (score 0):

To expand on [Tj3n](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5230311/tj3n)'s comment above, I suggest you store your images on disk, as PNGs or JPEGs, and store a `List<RealmImage>` as a property where `RealmImage` is a Realm model containing image metadata you want to store, along with a path to the location of the PNG/JPEG on disk.